# Why is there no @ConformsTo for @FunctionalInterface in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, api-design, functional-interface

Java (1.8+) has an @FunctionalInterface annotation which (basically) suggests that you can pass a method reference in place of an Interface implementation to another method call. The useful one I was playing with today is:

```
DateTimeFormatter.parse(String, TemporalQuery<T>)
```

It's nice as it lets you tell the formatter what kind of result to hand back to you. The javadoc even gives you a nice example:

```
The query is typically a method reference to a from(TemporalAccessor) method. For example: 
  LocalDateTime dt = parser.parse(str, LocalDateTime::from);
```

Once I got my head around what the @FunctionalInterface is and means, I started to wonder how a consumer of an API is to figure out what they can actually use in its place. The example above tells you what you can use, and if you trace through the java.time package, you can find other method references you can use. However, any contributors to the API need to read through the entire javadoc to make sure they don't break any implicit contracts mentioned in other places (of course they should, especially for the JDK, but that's not the purpose of javadoc!)

So.. If a contributor to this API were to change the signature of LocalDateTime::from, then there's no compile time checking to say that this method no longer conforms to the FuncitonalInterface of 'TemporalQuery'. This would obviously break any consumers of the API and they could change their code to use an explicit lambda instead. I do understand that it does not need to, but if an annotation, similar to the optional '@Override' annotation were available, then it would provide some compile time checks as well as the possibility of introspecting/reflecting to discover available method references.

e.g.

```
@ConformsTo(TemporalQuery.class)
public static LocalDateTime from(TemporalAccessor temporal)
```

It would also then be possible to find, through introspection, any other method references that can be used for a FunctionalInterface.

So, to be clear, I understand that this is not necessary, but do think it seems to be an oversight not to include it as an optional Annotation. Is there any particular reason this could/should not exist?

Comment: Note that `@FunctionalInterface` doesn't _allow_ you to pass a method reference, it _indicates_ that the interface is _meant to be used this way_. You're allowed to pass a method reference even when that annotation is missing on the interface.

Comment: Yes, I did hope that using '(basically)' would get me out of the semantics but you're right, I should make that clearer:)

Comment: You can place a `static { if(false) { TemporalQuery verify = LocalDateTime::from; } }` into the code…

Answer (score 1):

The problems that arise from changing the signature or return type of a method, e.g. LocalDateTime::from isn't limited to functional interfaces. Even before Java 8 changing those things risked breaking existing code that relied on those things. That's why designing an API is always a challenge because changes to existing code can mean a lot of work.

Additionally, assuming the functional interface and the matching methods are part of different libraries, would you really want that they are closely coupled, i.e. both need to change when one changes? What if they are maintained by different organizations (let's say different open source projects or companies) - how should they coordinate?

As an example take `Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)`. That basically accepts a reference to any method that takes no parameter and returns something comparable. There are so many libraries that already provide those methods, would you want them all to have to add `@ConformsTo`?

That said, a `@ConformsTo` would at best be incomplete and might even be misleading/outdated.

**Edit:**

Let's tackle both annotations from the view of the compiler.

`@FunctionalInterface` tells the compiler that it should complain when you define more than one abstract method or use it on something else other than an interface.

That means that the requirements/contract definition ("this interface is a functional interface") and the implementation (the interface itself) are contained in the same file and thus have to be changed together anyways.

`@ConformsTo` could tell the compiler to check the requirements of the functional interface (or even interfaces) and see if that method satisfies them.

So far so good, but the problem arises when the interface changes: it would couple the method and the interface which could be part of different and otherwise totally unrelated libraries. And even if they were part of the same library you could run into problems when the method itself wouldn't be recompiled - the compiler might miss that incompatibility and thus defy the purpose of that annotation (if it were only meant for humans then a simple comment would be sufficient as well).

Comment: We've been having an extended debate around the coffee machine about this. LocalDateTime::from isn't, and nor should it be, limited to that functional interface, but the JavaDoc says it 'can' be used for this. You wouldn't be able to write this across multiple APIs without introducing an explicit dependency, which is no different to just implementing an interface provided by someone else. I'm saying that if you are writing the API to begin with, you COULD provide an explicit contract rather than just a comment saying 'this will work for now'

Comment: @beirtipol well, considering that both the method and the interface are part of the same library it's ok to provide some hint as to how this can be used. Besides that, functional interfaces, lambdas etc. are actually not much different from the old way of implementing some interface - it just allows for a much nicer syntax. The problem with explicit contracts is that it's hard to really enforce them across multiple libraries so having them might lead to a "false sense of security" (for lack of a better term).

Comment: I'm only asking if it should be available to be useful for maintainers of a single library. I'm really not suggesting that it "must" be used. There's no 'necessity' to have this. There's also no 'necessity' to have 'final' as a class level keyword, but it does serve a useful purpose when you have multiple contributors to an API.

Comment: @beirtipol actually, there's a difference between `final` and `@ConformsTo`: with `final` _you_ define what can be done and what can't and users of your api can't change that - you define the rules of the contract. `@ConformsTo` would describe that you intend to fulfill a contract, but you're not the one who defines it so it could change without you knowing it or being able to do something about it.

Comment: @beirtipol I also didn't mean you said it _must_ be used or not. You were asking why it doesn't exist and my answer was: it probably would do more harm (in form of misleading or outdated information) than good (provide a set of matching methods). In fact, you'd need to use an IDE anyways so that IDE could also just scan the code base and match methods that fit the required signature and return value - without having the developer add and maintain an annotation. `@FunctionalInterface` on the other hand enable the compiler to complain when you declare more than one abstract method.